# Scala-Play Json: How to define a Writes for any Saddle Frame?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, saddle

I have a Scala-Play web services application that does a bit of computations that generate [Saddle frames](http://saddle.github.io/doc/quickstart.html) and need to dump those Saddle frames into Json. So I define a `frameWrites` like this:

```
object JsonUtils {
  implicit def frameWrites[RX, CX, E] = new Writes[Frame[RX, CX, E]] {
    override def writes(frame: Frame[RX, CX, E]): JsValue = {
      val json: JsArray = Json.arr(
        (0 until frame.numRows).map { i =>
          Json.obj(
            frame.rowIx.at(i).toString ->
              (0 until frame.numCols).map { j =>
                Json.obj(
                  frame.colIx.at(j).toString -> frame.at(i, j).toString
                )
              }
          )
        })
        json
      }
  }
}
```

and then attempt to use it like this:

```
import utils.JsonUtils._

def computingAction = Action {
   val pnlStatistics: Frame[String, String, Double] = ???
   Ok(pnlStatistics) 
}
```

but then always get the error `Cannot write an instance of org.saddle.Frame[String,String,Double] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[org.saddle.Frame[String,String,Double]]`

To be really explicit I have also tried defining as part of `JsonUtils`:

```
implicit def frameSSDWrites = frameWrites[String, String, Double]
```

but this one also doesn't get picked up ...

**UPDATE** invoking the writer explicitly works:

```
Ok(frameWrites.writes(results("PnlStatistics")))
```

Comment: but you need to implement Writeable not a Writes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Play result input must be some content that can be put in a HTTP response.

Your action does not know that you want to write it specifically as JSON, so you need to return `Ok(Json.toJson(pnlStatistics))`.

Let us see how this work:

- The type of `pnlStatistics` is a `Frame`, so you can serialize it to JSON, using your implicit `Writes[Frame]`, so `Json.toJson` accepts it as parameter. It then returns a `JsValue`.
- Since there is also an implicit `Writeable[JsValue]` in scope, `Ok` then accepts this value as content for your response (and will also add the `Content-Type` header).

If you forget the explicit `JSON` conversion, Play has no way to determine how you want the frame handled in the response.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and well grounded answer! I checked it and worked perfectly.